# How to lock Access 2010 record after it has been saved?

Tags: security, microsoft-access-2010, lock

How can I create a macro to permanently lock a record once it has been saved?

My problem: every Access 2010 lock command that makes the saved records un-editable, also locks the 'New Record' form fields, so that no new record can be added to the database.
I need to lock what has been saved, and at the same time keep adding new records.

Answer (score 1):

In Access 2010 and later, what you've described is dead simple to implement with a Before Change data macro on the table:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

For more information on data macros see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a VBA solution, you should use [`DoCmd.OpenTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194975%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [`acAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835947%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as datamode property

```
Sub AddOnlyMode()    
    DoCmd.OpenTable "table1", acViewNormal, acAdd    
End Sub
```

If you execute it, an existing table called "table1" will be opened. You won't see old existing entries. You could only add new entries and edit them too as long as you don't close the table.

Once you have closed the table (saving isn't enough), your entries are locked. Opening the table again **via VBA** won't show any entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock `field1` try the following:

```
Private Sub Field1_GotFocus()  
    If Me.Field1.Text  "" Then   
      Me.Field1.Locked = True  
    Else  
      Me.Field1.Locked = False  
    End If
End Sub
```